# find equation based on multiple sets of 2 variables and results

Tags: evolutionary-game-theory

I'm currently trying to reverse engineer a few equations used in a game, and have collected what seems to be all the relevant data.

In the example below, result speed is definitely based solely on the variables of thrust and weight. note that the game does use variables, but rounds the number. There also seems to be diminishing returns on thrust, apart from the increase in weight which comes with it.

thrust | weight | speed

428 | 13575 | 188

617 | 13575 | 209

536 | 23850 | 152

995 | 35750 | 175

698 | 17475 | 202

1373 | 8575 | 278

Is it possible for me to use this data to find the equation through any means except brute force? I've looked around but only found things which used a single variable.

Not sure how to tag this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a question better suited for [reverse engineering stackexchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). But my guess is you could try to hold  one variable constant and find a relation between the other 2, do it the same for each variable and then try to find a approximate relation between them. Improve upon it with better and better data.
Since it's a game,i guess there could be a way to hold  the weight constant easily .